# Restoring an open file

Tags: files, solaris, data-recovery

I have an interesting problem which may or may not have a solution but I'd love to have one if possible:

On Solaris an open log file has been removed, which still continues to be populated while the process is running but is now inaccessible to all the other tools like `cat`, `tail`, etc.

Is there any way to restore the entry in the directory to this file while everything keeps running?

Comment: I know [this is impossible under Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29557/capturing-new-output-after-deleting-the-output-file/29606#29606). I don't know about Solaris.

Comment: The tail of /proc/PID/fd trick in the link @Gilles left might help you copy the contents out, but i suspect you'll no longer be able to re-link the file as with linux.

Comment: @dbenhur, there is no need to relink. You can use `tail -c +1 -f /proc/pid/fd/num > /logfile` to keep the original file (name) in sync with is active file descriptor data. The issue with this solution is that, especially with buffered output but not only, you'll likely miss the last lines when the original writing process dies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is doable, with some hacking and limitations (you need root privileges).

First find what file descriptor is using the application to write the log file then create a symbolic link in the previous log file location and pointing to the file /proc entry, eg:

```
ln -s /var/tmp/file.log /proc/12345/fd/3
```

The first limitation is that if the file was only open for writing by the process, its permission won't allow an unprivileged user to read its content. However, root and users with the file_dac_read privilege won't be affected. Alternatively, you can use a process to copy the file contents with `tail` like Gilles is suggesting in his comment. eg:

```
tail -c +1 -f /proc/12345/fd/5 > /var/tmp/file.log
```

The second issue is that the whole file content will be lost (`ln -s`) or part of it (`tail -c 1 -f`) when the process either closes it or exits.

A workaround is to use a program that monitors this event and backup the file before close is actually called.

Likely tools to do the job are dtrace, truss, mdb, or dbx.

Here is a proof of concept using dtrace on Solaris 10.

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# This dtrace script is monitoring a file descriptor for a given process
# and copy its content to the given path when the file is closed.
#

pid=${1:?"$0: Usage: pid fd path"}
fd=${2:?}
path=${3:?}
[[ -f $path ]] && { echo "$path exists"; exit 1; }
dtrace -w -n '
syscall::close:entry
/pid=='$pid' && arg0=='$fd'/
{
        stop();
        system("cp /proc/%d/fd/%d %s",pid,arg0,"'"$path"'");
        system("prun %d",pid);
        exit(0);
}'
```